# is it possible to run multiple executables in a shell script with the same PID?

Tags: linux, process, executable

I have a simple Shell script in which multiple executables will run sequentially. Every time a new executable starts to run, a new process with a new PID will start. Is it possible to run them with the same PID? I know for a shell script, we can use "source". But I do not know how to handle executables.

Comment: No, it is not possible. All newly launched processes get a new PID.  PIDs get reused eventually, but this is not under your control.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is a very strange requirement, and I feel like you're really trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I try to run some workload that is an executable. I want it to run forever. So I want to put it into a while loop in a shell script. Due to the performance monitoring reason, I need to get the PID of the workload. That's the reason why I do not like the PID to change from time to time

Comment: Why don't you just have the script write the child process's PID to a file every time it restarts that process? Then your performance monitor can just re-load the file once it notices the process it is monitoring is gone.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Seems to be one option.My original concern is that the PID change frequency might be higher than the monitoring tool re-invoking frequency. So I may want to invoke the tool frequently enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, I believe it should be possible, but in practice it would be very complicated and brittle.

The `exec` family of system calls in Linux allows a process to replace itself with an entirely new process, which holds on to the same PID. The tricky part would be to somehow "return" from the second process back to the first. When `exec` is called, the OS loads everything it needs to start running the new process, and wipes out every piece of state related to the current process (the one being replaced). And when the new process terminates, the OS releases all resources (including the PID) associated with that process.

So if you really wanted to do this, you would have to hijack how processes terminate in order to restart your original process rather than let the OS clean everything up. How can you do this? Well, `execle` and `execvpe` functions allow a program to specify the *environment* of the new process before starting the process. Since every process depends on `libc` (or equivalent) to bring up/tear down a process, you should be able to provide a custom `libc` which would re-start execution of your script, or `exec` another process. The great difficulty would be hacking such a `libc`. Additionally, you would have to figure out a good way for your master program to keep state even though the OS wipes away any memory it might have been using when it called `exec`. You can probably accomplish this with temporary files.

So long story short, don't do it. While it's kind of fun for me to sit here and think about the massive hacks that would be required to pull this off, it would be a huge pain and I'm sure there is a much more elegant solution to whatever problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Another option may be to change the source code of the workload and wrap all the content in main() function in a while loop

Answer (score 1):

The PID is assigned by OS when shell creates a new process. There is no way to tell the OS to use some specific PID. So it's not possible.